# Is there anyway to add a user to multiple groups in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to add 20 users to 30 different groups in SharePoint.

Is there anyway to add a user to multiple groups in sharepoint 2010 at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Powershell to achive this task
Open notepad and write the following script

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$Groups =("Group1","Group2")
foreach($g in $Groups)
{
  Set-SPUser -Identity 'domain\username' -Web http://yoursite -Group $g
}
```

Now save this script with PS extension then by right click on it you can run this script.

More information check the following article
[Set-SPUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607827.aspx)

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Just wanted to add that I was getting an error with the Set-SPUser (You must specify a valid user object), So I used the New-SPUser command instead as follows New-SPUser -UserAlias 'domain\username'  - Web http://yoursite -Group $g